# Best-practice of setting up Jenkins-in-Docker with Docker-in-Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I am developing an application for which I would like continuous integration using Jenkins, furthermore I would like to be able to control the environment for CI. I am developing locally on OS X, and I am pushing to a remote Ubuntu 16.04 VM. **All of this lead me to Docker.** Basically what I want is Jenkins-in-Docker, but also Docker-in-Jenkins. My build slave(s) will initially be limited to just *master*.

Now, I've been reading some posts about Docker for the past few days, but I am still not entirely sure I understand it in-depth, yet. Hence this question.

Currently, this is my setup:

**Jenkins:**

`/docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    build: ./jenkins
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # allowing docker-in-docker
      - ./jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

`/jenkins/Dockerfile`

```
FROM docker:17.12 AS docker
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

COPY --from=docker /usr/local/bin/docker /usr/local/bin/docker
```

The above setup works just fine - until I use Docker-in-Jenkins. Jenkins is installed and all, but when I'm building any jobs that would then *use* Docker, I get an error that

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon
>   socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post (...) dial unix
>   /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

**CI Source:**

`/Jenkinsfile`

```groovy
pipeline {
  agent { dockerfile true }
  stages {
    stage('Initial') {
      steps {
        println 'Hello world!'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

/Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6-slim-jessie
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
CMD ["python"]
```

**Now to the questions!**

First, obviously I am missing some permission for the container to use my host Docker daemon. I see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45447434/how-to-use-docker-from-inside-jenkins-docker-container) (among others) has some answers to that.

**Secondly, is this even the intended way of setting things up? I would like to learn docker the right way, and I don't know if I have missed something regarding e.g. multi-stage builds?**

Comment: Jenkins plugins and execution make assumptions about how things are setup which can make it difficult to try and move towards a setup like this using the existing plugins. A few ways to possibly speed this up (1) look at the Jenkins `docker` commands executed. Jenkins is controlling Docker execution you may be surprised at what you find (2) Try to draw a picture of the containers, volume mounts, users and groups of each container (I've done this before, found it personally helpful) (3) figure it out locally first. Learning this on Jenkins first is what I would call "the hard way".

Comment: So, for the `Got permission denied` - my first guess is that even though the Docker client can communicate with the socket, it does not have the right user/group to use. If you try mounting a file owned by `root` into your workspace and try reading it, you would probably see a similar error. I would suggest running `stat -c %g /var/run/docker.sock` on the agent to see what the owning group of the Docker socket is, and adding `args  '--group-add=that-group-id'` (from [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run)) and see if that gets you any further.

Comment: Have you read the Docker recommended blog article about this: https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/? Note the warning at the end about copying the Docker binary executable in recent versions of Docker. You should probably remove that from your Jenkins Dockerfile's last line.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this Dockerfile for jenkins with docker.

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
MAINTAINER "artem@aleksashkin.com" Artem Aleksashkin

USER root
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install apt-transport-https \
         ca-certificates \
         curl \
         gnupg2 \
         software-properties-common && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID")/gpg > /tmp/dkey; apt-key add /tmp/dkey && \
    add-apt-repository \
       "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID") \
       $(lsb_release -cs) \
       stable" && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install docker-ce && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.22.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && \
    usermod -aG docker jenkins

USER jenkins
```

Comment: Nice snippet. Made my life easy. Could you please add openssh-server to install along with the docker? ssh will be required if someone wants to use the jenkins as a slave & to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins

USER root

RUN apt-get update RUN apt-get -y install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg2 \
    software-properties-common RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID")/gpg | apt-key add - RUN add-apt-repository \    "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID") \   $(lsb_release -cs) \    stable" RUN apt-get update RUN apt-get -y install docker-ce

USER jenkins
```